Caching in Spring (with Redis or similar)
We are using Spring caching with Redis.   We have a situation where many requests may come in at the exact same time for a given database query (invoked in a method decorated with @cacheable.   I'm wondering whether out-of-box, Spring (and or Redis) is smart enough to force subsequent identical requests to wait for the initial cache entry to populate.  In js we would do this be caching a Promise, rather than the data itself.  I can't seem to find any documentation around this.  EHCache once offered something called a BlockingCache with this feature.
Again, this is a question about the scenario when the cache is cold and multiple requests come in that invoke the same very expensive database query.
